# d3 add text to circle

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to add some text into circle. I have been following example from [a mbostock tutorial](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/circle.html), but wasn't able to get the right output.

The code snippet is:

```
var data;
var code;

d3.json("/json/trace.json", function(json) {
  data = json;
  console.log(data);
  // get code for visualization
  code = data["code"];
  alert(code);
  var mainSVG = d3
    .select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 900)
    .attr("height", 900);
  mainSVG
    .append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", 100)
    .attr("cx", 300)
    .attr("cy", 300);
  circle = mainSVG.selectAll("circle").data([code]);
});
```

Any suggestions how to get this work?

Comment: Perhaps, take a step back and drop the json until you have a grip on the theory. http://tributary.io/inlet/4132672/ (live example, as presented by enjalot in this [video](http://vimeo.com/49741439). I strongly suggest checking the other d3 videos he has.

Comment: I tried with simple example from the link provided and couldn't get it to work.. Thanks anyway

Comment: you didn't see 3 circles with text inside?

Comment: nope - that's why I'm asking  :)

Comment: are you per chance using firefox ?

Comment: I'm using chrome :) and I can see demo from the page working but mine not :)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Here is an example showing some text in circles with data from a json file: http://bl.ocks.org/4474971. Which gives the following:

[image]

The main idea behind this is to encapsulate the text and the circle in the same "`div`" as you would do in html to have the logo and the name of the company in the same `div` in a page header.

The main code is:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;
 
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    
d3.json("data.json", function(json) {
    /* Define the data for the circles */
    var elem = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(json.nodes)
  
    /*Create and place the "blocks" containing the circle and the text */  
    var elemEnter = elem.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate("+d.x+",80)"})
 
    /*Create the circle for each block */
    var circle = elemEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d){return d.r} )
        .attr("stroke","black")
        .attr("fill", "white")
 
    /* Create the text for each block */
    elemEnter.append("text")
        .attr("dx", function(d){return -20})
        .text(function(d){return d.label})
})
```

and the json file is:

```
{"nodes":[
  {"x":80, "r":40, "label":"Node 1"}, 
  {"x":200, "r":60, "label":"Node 2"}, 
  {"x":380, "r":80, "label":"Node 3"}
]}
```

The resulting html code shows the encapsulation you want:

```
<svg width="960" height="500">
    <g transform="translate(80,80)">
        <circle r="40" stroke="black" fill="white"></circle>
        <text dx="-20">Node 1</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(200,80)">
        <circle r="60" stroke="black" fill="white"></circle>
        <text dx="-20">Node 2</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(380,80)">
        <circle r="80" stroke="black" fill="white"></circle>
        <text dx="-20">Node 3</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

jsfiddle with working code: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/DY7r4/

Comment: Jup, it's not showing anything - even when I fix ';' from .attr("cy", 300); As long as I have code that is not adding some text it works

Answer (score 6):

Extended the example above to fit the actual requirements, where circled is filled with solid background color, then with striped pattern & after that text node is placed on the center of the circle.

```js
var width = 960,
  height = 500,
  json = {
    "nodes": [{
      "x": 100,
      "r": 20,
      "label": "Node 1",
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "x": 200,
      "r": 25,
      "label": "Node 2",
      "color": "blue"
    }, {
      "x": 300,
      "r": 30,
      "label": "Node 3",
      "color": "green"
    }]
  };

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

svg.append("defs")
  .append("pattern")
  .attr({
    "id": "stripes",
    "width": "8",
    "height": "8",
    "fill": "red",
    "patternUnits": "userSpaceOnUse",
    "patternTransform": "rotate(60)"
  })
  .append("rect")
  .attr({
    "width": "4",
    "height": "8",
    "transform": "translate(0,0)",
    "fill": "grey"
  });

function plotChart(json) {
  /* Define the data for the circles */
  var elem = svg.selectAll("g myCircleText")
    .data(json.nodes)

  /*Create and place the "blocks" containing the circle and the text */
  var elemEnter = elem.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node-group")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + ",80)"
    })

  /*Create the circle for each block */
  var circleInner = elemEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.r
    })
    .attr("stroke", function(d) {
      return d.color;
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return d.color;
    });

  var circleOuter = elemEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.r
    })
    .attr("stroke", function(d) {
      return d.color;
    })
    .attr("fill", "url(#stripes)");

  /* Create the text for each block */
  elemEnter.append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.label
    })
    .attr({
      "text-anchor": "middle",
      "font-size": function(d) {
        return d.r / ((d.r * 10) / 100);
      },
      "dy": function(d) {
        return d.r / ((d.r * 25) / 100);
      }
    });
};

plotChart(json);
```

```css
.node-group {
  fill: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Below is the link to `codepen` also:

See the Pen [D3-Circle-Pattern-Text](http://codepen.io/mkdudeja/pen/grgErY/) by Manish Kumar ([@mkdudeja](http://codepen.io/mkdudeja)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

Thanks,
Manish Kumar

Comment: Hi, A small help is needed. In my case the text between the circle is hiding behind. If I increase the opacity of the circle I can see the text, but it is hidden if the circle color is solid. Am I missing something which brings the text above the circle. Thanks

Comment: The only problem which can be is make sure you write text on circles only after circles are created. If you write text before circles get created, then text will not be visible. Basically in D3 everything is a layer. Layer created later will override the earlier one.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way that I consider easier: 
The general idea is that you want to append a text element to a circle element then play around with its "dx"  and "dy" attributes until you position the text at the point in the circle that you like. In my example, I used a negative number for the dx since I wanted to have text start towards the left of the centre.

```
const nodes = [ {id: ABC, group: 1, level: 1}, {id:XYZ, group: 2, level: 1}, ]

const nodeElems = svg.append('g')
.selectAll('circle')
.data(nodes)
.enter().append('circle')
.attr('r',radius)
.attr('fill', getNodeColor)

const textElems = svg.append('g')
.selectAll('text')
.data(nodes)
.enter().append('text')
.text(node => node.label)
.attr('font-size',8)//font size
.attr('dx', -10)//positions text towards the left of the center of the circle
.attr('dy',4)
```