# how to create circles with text over svg file using d3 js?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I am a beginner to d3 js. I have a div that contains a object tag having svg file.
I need to create circle with texts over that svg file and bind click functions over them using d3 js.
Thanx in advance. Below is my html code:

```
<div class="span8 canvasDiv">
    <object data="img/floor.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="floorCanvas"></object>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("#floorCanvas");
var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
                         .attr("cx", 30)
                         .attr("cy", 30)
                         .attr("r", 20);
```

Comment: Where is your `d3` code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [d3 add text to circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615381/d3-add-text-to-circle)

Comment: @thisOneGuy: your reffred question is creating svg tag. but in my case i have an svg tag inside object tag.

Answer (score 0):

youll need to create a 'g' tag then append both the circle and the text to that 'g' as you cant append text directly to an svg shape so something like this (not tested) :

HTML :

```
 <div class="span8 canvasDiv">
        <object data="img/floor.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="floorCanvas"></object>
        </div>
```

JS Code:-

```
 var svgContainer = d3.select("#floorCanvas").append('svg').append('g').attr('id', 'circleWithText');
 var circleWithText = d3.select("#circleWithText");

 circleWithText .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", 30)
                .attr("cy", 30)
                .attr("r", 20);

 circleWithText.append('text')
                .attr('class', 'text')
                .attr("dx", "0")
                .attr("dy", "0")
                .text('what ever you want here');
```

CSS

```
.text{
    text-anchor: middle;
    color: steelblue;
    position:relative;
    font: 14px Calibri;
}
```

Something along those lines :)

Comment: Thanx for your code. I was able to add text over the svg file. But the circle is not visible. Its tag has been created but not visible.

Comment: why are you using an object tag ?

Comment: Well, I found no other way except object tag and embed tag for loading svg file.

Comment: displayed the circle using this : `var svgContainer = d3.select("#floorCanvas").append('svg').append('g').attr('id', 'circleWithText');`

Comment: and all you want to is display a circle ? how come you have image link in the object tag ? What i would say is dont use object use svg instead

Comment: Can i load my svg file inside svg tag ?

Comment: yeah dont see why not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79294/discussion-between-rahul-munjal-and-thisoneguy).