# JSON local data file not parsing

Tags: javascript, html

I am fairly new to `JSON` and since I am running on a client machine and cant have access to a web server, i am being forced to include my data files within the `HTML` code - I am yet struggling to get this working - it is my `JSON.PARSE()` part of the code

Apologies for the length of the code, its mostly data variable

-- can anyone help ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var datajson = {
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Myriel", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Napoleon", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1},
    {"id": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Geborand", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Champtercier", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Cravatte", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Count", "group": 1},
    {"id": "OldMan", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Labarre", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Valjean", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Marguerite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.deR", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Isabeau", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Gervais", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Tholomyes", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Listolier", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fameuil", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Blacheville", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Favourite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Dahlia", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Zephine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fantine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Cosette", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Javert", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Fauchelevent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Bamatabois", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Perpetue", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Simplice", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Scaufflaire", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Woman1", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Judge", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Champmathieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Brevet", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Chenildieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Cochepaille", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Pontmercy", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Boulatruelle", "group": 6},
    {"id": "Eponine", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Anzelma", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Woman2", "group": 5},
    {"id": "MotherInnocent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Gribier", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Jondrette", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Mme.Burgon", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Gavroche", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Magnon", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mme.Pontmercy", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Vaubois", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Lt.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Marius", "group": 8},
    {"id": "BaronessT", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mabeuf", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Enjolras", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Combeferre", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Prouvaire", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Feuilly", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Courfeyrac", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Bahorel", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Bossuet", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Joly", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Grantaire", "group": 8},
    {"id": "MotherPlutarch", "group": 9},
    {"id": "Gueulemer", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Babet", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Claquesous", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Montparnasse", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Toussaint", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Child1", "group": 10},
    {"id": "Child2", "group": 10},
    {"id": "Brujon", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Mme.Hucheloup", "group": 8}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Myriel", "value": 10},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 6},
    {"source": "CountessdeLo", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Geborand", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Champtercier", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cravatte", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Count", "target": "Myriel", "value": 2},
    {"source": "OldMan", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Labarre", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mme.Magloire", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Myriel", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Marguerite", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.deR", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Isabeau", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gervais", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Listolier", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Favourite", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Zephine", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Marguerite", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Valjean", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 13},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 12},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Valjean", "value": 31},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Valjean", "value": 17},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Fantine", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 8},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Perpetue", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Perpetue", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Scaufflaire", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Chenildieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Pontmercy", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Boulatruelle", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Eponine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 3},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gribier", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Burgon", "target": "Jondrette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Mme.Burgon", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Vaubois", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 12},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Lt.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Cosette", "value": 21},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Valjean", "value": 19},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Eponine", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 4},
    {"source": "BaronessT", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "BaronessT", "target": "Marius", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Marius", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Marius", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Javert", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Valjean", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 15},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Marius", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Marius", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Marius", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 17},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 13},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Marius", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Marius", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 12},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 10},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Marius", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Joly", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 1},
    {"source": "MotherPlutarch", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Javert", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Babet", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Babet", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Child1", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Child2", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Child2", "target": "Child1", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Babet", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Montparnasse", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Joly", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Grantaire", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1}
  ]
};

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

//d3.json(datajson, function(error, graph) {
  JSON.parse(datajson, function (error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: try removing the semicolon at the end of json

Comment: You have no JSON in your page, so no need to call `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: what you talkin bout willis, its a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - great input to my problem tho

Comment: It's not JSON just because it has curly braces. JSON always is a string. If it's not a string, it's not JSON. Try to remember this early on, many misuse the word, don't become one of them. JSON tag removed.

Answer (score 4):

`datajson` is already an object, applying `JSON.parse` therefore doesn't make sense / work. Parsing as JSON would be only useful to convert it from string (like `"{"nodes":[{"id":"Myriel","group":1},{"id":"Napoleon","group":1},..."` to an object as you already have.

If you want to keep your object as it is, you just have to delete the `JSON.parse`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .links line {
        stroke: #999;
        stroke-opacity: 0.6;
    }

    .nodes circle {
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var graph = {
        "nodes": [
            { "id": "Myriel", "group": 1 },
            { "id": "Napoleon", "group": 1 },
            { "id": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1 },
            { "id": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1 },
            { "id": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1 },
            { "id": "Geborand", "group": 1 },
            { "id": "Champtercier", "group": 1 },
            { "id": "Cravatte", "group": 1 },
            { "id": "Count", "group": 1 },
            { "id": "OldMan", "group": 1 },
            { "id": "Labarre", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Valjean", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Marguerite", "group": 3 },
            { "id": "Mme.deR", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Isabeau", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Gervais", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Tholomyes", "group": 3 },
            { "id": "Listolier", "group": 3 },
            { "id": "Fameuil", "group": 3 },
            { "id": "Blacheville", "group": 3 },
            { "id": "Favourite", "group": 3 },
            { "id": "Dahlia", "group": 3 },
            { "id": "Zephine", "group": 3 },
            { "id": "Fantine", "group": 3 },
            { "id": "Mme.Thenardier", "group": 4 },
            { "id": "Thenardier", "group": 4 },
            { "id": "Cosette", "group": 5 },
            { "id": "Javert", "group": 4 },
            { "id": "Fauchelevent", "group": 0 },
            { "id": "Bamatabois", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Perpetue", "group": 3 },
            { "id": "Simplice", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Scaufflaire", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Woman1", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Judge", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Champmathieu", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Brevet", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Chenildieu", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Cochepaille", "group": 2 },
            { "id": "Pontmercy", "group": 4 },
            { "id": "Boulatruelle", "group": 6 },
            { "id": "Eponine", "group": 4 },
            { "id": "Anzelma", "group": 4 },
            { "id": "Woman2", "group": 5 },
            { "id": "MotherInnocent", "group": 0 },
            { "id": "Gribier", "group": 0 },
            { "id": "Jondrette", "group": 7 },
            { "id": "Mme.Burgon", "group": 7 },
            { "id": "Gavroche", "group": 8 },
            { "id": "Gillenormand", "group": 5 },
            { "id": "Magnon", "group": 5 },
            { "id": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "group": 5 },
            { "id": "Mme.Pontmercy", "group": 5 },
            { "id": "Mlle.Vaubois", "group": 5 },
            { "id": "Lt.Gillenormand", "group": 5 },
            { "id": "Marius", "group": 8 },
            { "id": "BaronessT", "group": 5 },
            { "id": "Mabeuf", "group": 8 },
            { "id": "Enjolras", "group": 8 },
            { "id": "Combeferre", "group": 8 },
            { "id": "Prouvaire", "group": 8 },
            { "id": "Feuilly", "group": 8 },
            { "id": "Courfeyrac", "group": 8 },
            { "id": "Bahorel", "group": 8 },
            { "id": "Bossuet", "group": 8 },
            { "id": "Joly", "group": 8 },
            { "id": "Grantaire", "group": 8 },
            { "id": "MotherPlutarch", "group": 9 },
            { "id": "Gueulemer", "group": 4 },
            { "id": "Babet", "group": 4 },
            { "id": "Claquesous", "group": 4 },
            { "id": "Montparnasse", "group": 4 },
            { "id": "Toussaint", "group": 5 },
            { "id": "Child1", "group": 10 },
            { "id": "Child2", "group": 10 },
            { "id": "Brujon", "group": 4 },
            { "id": "Mme.Hucheloup", "group": 8 }
        ],
        "links": [
            { "source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8 },
            { "source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Myriel", "value": 10 },
            { "source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 6 },
            { "source": "CountessdeLo", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Geborand", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Champtercier", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Cravatte", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Count", "target": "Myriel", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "OldMan", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Valjean", "target": "Labarre", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Valjean", "target": "Mme.Magloire", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Valjean", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Valjean", "target": "Myriel", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Marguerite", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mme.deR", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Isabeau", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Gervais", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Listolier", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Fameuil", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Fameuil", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Blacheville", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Blacheville", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Blacheville", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Favourite", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Favourite", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Favourite", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Favourite", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Dahlia", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Dahlia", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Dahlia", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Dahlia", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Dahlia", "target": "Favourite", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Zephine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Zephine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Zephine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Zephine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Zephine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Zephine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Zephine", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Marguerite", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Valjean", "value": 9 },
            { "source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 7 },
            { "source": "Thenardier", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 13 },
            { "source": "Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 12 },
            { "source": "Cosette", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Cosette", "target": "Valjean", "value": 31 },
            { "source": "Cosette", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Cosette", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Javert", "target": "Valjean", "value": 17 },
            { "source": "Javert", "target": "Fantine", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Javert", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Javert", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Javert", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 8 },
            { "source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Perpetue", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Simplice", "target": "Perpetue", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Simplice", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Simplice", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Simplice", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Scaufflaire", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Woman1", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Woman1", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Judge", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Judge", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Brevet", "target": "Judge", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Brevet", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Brevet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Brevet", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Judge", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Chenildieu", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Pontmercy", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Boulatruelle", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Eponine", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Eponine", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Anzelma", "target": "Eponine", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Anzelma", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Anzelma", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Woman2", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Woman2", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Woman2", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Gribier", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Mme.Burgon", "target": "Jondrette", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Gavroche", "target": "Mme.Burgon", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Gavroche", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Gavroche", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Gavroche", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Magnon", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Magnon", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 9 },
            { "source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mlle.Vaubois", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Marius", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 6 },
            { "source": "Marius", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 12 },
            { "source": "Marius", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Marius", "target": "Lt.Gillenormand", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Marius", "target": "Cosette", "value": 21 },
            { "source": "Marius", "target": "Valjean", "value": 19 },
            { "source": "Marius", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Marius", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Marius", "target": "Eponine", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Marius", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "BaronessT", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "BaronessT", "target": "Marius", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Marius", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Enjolras", "target": "Marius", "value": 7 },
            { "source": "Enjolras", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7 },
            { "source": "Enjolras", "target": "Javert", "value": 6 },
            { "source": "Enjolras", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Enjolras", "target": "Valjean", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Combeferre", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 15 },
            { "source": "Combeferre", "target": "Marius", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Combeferre", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 6 },
            { "source": "Combeferre", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Feuilly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Feuilly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 6 },
            { "source": "Feuilly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Feuilly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Feuilly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Feuilly", "target": "Marius", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Marius", "value": 9 },
            { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 17 },
            { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 13 },
            { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7 },
            { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6 },
            { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 6 },
            { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Marius", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Marius", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 12 },
            { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 10 },
            { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6 },
            { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 9 },
            { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Joly", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Joly", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 7 },
            { "source": "Joly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Joly", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Joly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Joly", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Joly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Joly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Joly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Joly", "target": "Marius", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Joly", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "MotherPlutarch", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5 },
            { "source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Babet", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 6 },
            { "source": "Babet", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 6 },
            { "source": "Babet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Babet", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Babet", "target": "Javert", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Babet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Babet", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Babet", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 4 },
            { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Babet", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Toussaint", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Toussaint", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Toussaint", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Child1", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Child2", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2 },
            { "source": "Child2", "target": "Child1", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Babet", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3 },
            { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Montparnasse", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Joly", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Grantaire", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
            { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1 }
        ]
    };

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height");

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    var link = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

    var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.group); })
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended));

    node.append("title")
        .text(function (d) { return d.id; });

    simulation
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
        .links(graph.links);

    function ticked() {
        link
            .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

        node
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; });
    }

    function dragstarted(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
    }

    function dragged(d) {
        d.fx = d3.event.x;
        d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }

    function dragended(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        d.fx = null;
        d.fy = null;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan, thats helpful, what would the syntax be ?

Comment: The correct usage when having a string would be `var obj = JSON.parse(str);`
What would you like to achieve? The `d3.json` could load JSON from an external file, for that you wouldn't need a webserver. In case you would like to keep your data embedded, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, appreciate your time with helping to do this. my end result is I want to replicate this example here https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

without having to import the data from a JSON file - Unfortunately no luck so far, and it doesn't seem to be attempted before by anyone. Would appreciate guidance if you have time recreating this (I know it could be minor tweaks to the code i have already, but I cant see where)

Comment: The modification I wrote works. I have uploaded the complete file to https://pastebin.com/5eHAh0Je

Comment: Cheers buddy, will look into it once i get home (pastebin is blocked form here)

Comment: Thanks Stephan, ur a legend - one last question, trying to get it ot write the label on the node, but having no luck at all - below my snippet, can you spot any issues ?

node.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", ".3em").text(function (d) { return (d.id); });

Comment: That appends the `text` element as a child of the `circle` element, which is not allowed. You could either wrap the `circle` with an additional `g` element (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615381/d3-add-text-to-circle ) or append the text to the nodes `g` and position it the same way as the circles.